# On ubuntu ,TypeError: chown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numeric_owner'

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying install MySQL-python on my computer which os is ubuntu,but it have a

> TypeError:TypeError: chown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numeric_owner'

**Detailed information:**

> ubuntua@ubuntua-Aspire-4736:~/Documents/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4$ python3 setup.py build
>   Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz
>   Extracting in /tmp/tmpuyexxhsu
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/ubuntua/Documents/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/distribute_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools
>       raise ImportError
>   ImportError
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "setup.py", line 7, in 
>       use_setuptools()
>     File "/home/ubuntua/Documents/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
>       return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
>     File "/home/ubuntua/Documents/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/distribute_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download
>       _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)
>     File "/home/ubuntua/Documents/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/distribute_setup.py", line 99, in _build_egg
>       _extractall(tar)
>     File "/home/ubuntua/Documents/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/distribute_setup.py", line 486, in _extractall
>       self.chown(tarinfo, dirpath)
>   TypeError: chown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numeric_owner'

I don't know how to solve this problem.Who can help me?Thannks!

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the code that prevents installing. It calls `chown` with bad arguments. Running `chown` as a non-privileged user is BTW pointless.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it looks like you are trying to install MySQL-python with Python 3. MySQL-python is not supported in Python 3 - as stated here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5

You may want to try mysqlclient instead : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient